# jquery vertical slider with display inline-block or float left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i've this HTML structure

```
<ul>
    <!-- Block 1 -->
    <li>Content 1</li>
    <li>Content 2</li>
    <li>Content 3</li>

    <!-- Block 2 -->
    <li>Content 4</li>
    <li>Content 5</li>
    <li>Content 6</li>

    <!-- Block 3 -->
    <li>Content 7</li>
    <li>Content 8</li>
    <li>Content 9</li>
</ul>
<a href="#">Previous</a>
<a href="#">Next</a>
```

The li tags have `float: left;` (or `display: inline-block;`) to display the content in columns, but when i use jquery vertical sliders, not working. Because `float: none;` appears from the jquery CSS declaration or `display block;`.

I need to maintain float or display, but i need a vertical (down/up) slider too.

Any suggest?

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/5g8YY/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a style element un JQuery which do the "float: left". The js style override the css style, so it's certainly the best way to do it.

Put your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ should be nice, because without your css and js content, it's difficult to help you therefore your problem is certainly from those code.